# How to select tags in the frontend

Tags: tags, front-end

Please help. I want users to be able to add posts from the frontend. It works for me, but I do not know how to do it to choose one of the existing tags. I have this code (used from here, but adjustable for my needs):

```
<?php
$taxonomies = array (
    'post_tag'
);
$args = array (
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'hide_empty' => false
);

$terms = get_terms($taxonomies, $args);

if(count($terms)> 0):

    foreach ($terms as $term):?>
        <div class="wissen_tag_list">
            <input type="radio" value="<?php echo $term->term_id; ?>" name="post_tag" class="post_tag_list" <?php if? php}?>>
            <label class="post_tag_list">
                <?php echo $term->name; ?>
            </label>
        </div>
<?php
    $i++; endforeach;
endif; ?>
```

My tags will appear, but there is no one to choose. Only the first one is selected. Can you please help me where I am wrong. These are standard tags, no custom.

[image: sample tags in the front end - there is no choice]

Thank you very much.

Comment: please remove space like (  $ i ++;  )

Comment: the spaces are inserted there - they are not in the code

Some idea? What am I wrong about?

Comment: Can you please tell me. That what type of problem are you facing.

Comment: I need to create new posts from the frontend. Everything is working. But I need to pick the tags from the list I define in the admin. Now I can write anything in the tag field and I do not want to.

The script I've loaded works - so I get all the tags, but they can not choose. It is marked only first and the other is not selected.

Maybe it's badly written, I'm not 100% sure of this. There may be another simpler solution.

Comment: Do you want to only be able to chose one tag at a time?  That's how you've got it set up currently.  otherwise you need to use checkboxes instead of radio inputs.  probably change the name from `post_tag` to `post_tag[]` as well.

Comment: I changed the check buttons - the same result. The first is checked and the other can not be selected.

When I change post_tag [], tag names will disappear altogether, and only 3 check boxes will appear from 3.

It would be best if he went to select only one tag, but if it was easier to choose more, I would not hinder it.